# Calculate number of Updation, Insertion and Deletion on a One String to reach Another String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have 2 user input strings and i need to check number of operations needed to be done on first string to generate second String
e.g:
String1: Morning
String2: Bring

No. of Operations = 3
Explanation: M and n are removed (2 operations) and o is replaced with B (1 operation)
Total 3 ops to convert 'Morning' to 'Bring'

e.g:
String1: Convert
String2: Contact
Operations = 3
Explanation: alphabets v,e,r from first string is converted to alphabets 't','a','c'

Note: It shouldn't remove an element from String 1 which is already in String 2 to check the position as in example 1, r in 'morning' remains unchanged even if positional value is different from second string 'bring'.

I tried converting it to character array and add null indexes to match characters but due to position index it didn't work

Comment: Operation? What are they? The question is rather unclear.

Comment: Although you're probably looking for "edit distance".

Comment: And you may consider formatting the question better to make it easier to read. Otherwise the question is not that bad.

Comment: Can you let me know what details are missing?

Comment: First I did point out that you didn't explain what operation means.

Comment: number of insertion, deletion, updation performed on first string is referred here as operation like i explained in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is known as [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

There is library called [Apache commons-text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/similarity/LevenshteinDistance.html#apply-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) that you can use to do it for you.

```
int ops = new LevenshteinDistance().apply(string1, string2)
```

Here is [source code](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/text/similarity/LevenshteinDistance.html#line.110)

Comment: Seems really helpful. Though I'm not using Apache for now.
Tried using import jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Levenshtein package but ran into some compile error. "Package jdk.internal.org.jline.utils is declared in module jdk.internal.le, which does not export it to the unnamed module".
Seems some file extension issue while importing packages.

Comment: But thanks a lot for your answer. Algo which i can get from packages will definitely help

Comment: @Pritam Consider [upvoting/accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) this answer if you find it helpful.